# Finding the error on SQL query when learning Inner join multitable

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am learning SQL and when doing some exercises this question showed up to me.
In matter of Multi-table consults I see sometimes that I can use Where clause instead of inner join, but Í try to use join because is the topic im trying to learn now. In this example I wrote this:

```
select p.nombre from pokemon p join pokemon_forma_evolucion pfe 
on p.numero_pokedex = pfe.numero_pokedex
join forma_evolucion fo 
on pfe.id_forma_evolucion = fo.id_forma_evolucion
join tipo_evolucion t
on t.tipo_evolucion = fo.tipo_evolucion
where lower(t.tipo_evolucion) = 'intercambio';
```

but it shows nothing. ( 0 results )

in the Exercises the correct answer by the blogger is this one and works fine showing 4 results :

```
select p.nombre
from pokemon p, pokemon_forma_evolucion pfe, 
forma_evolucion fe, tipo_evolucion te
where p.numero_pokedex = pfe.numero_pokedex 
and pfe.id_forma_evolucion = fe.id_forma_evolucion
and fe.tipo_evolucion = te.id_tipo_evolucion
and lower(te.tipo_evolucion) = 'intercambio';
```

I would like to know why mine is not working and how should I use the JOIN command properly. 
Link of the Exercises blog with DER and access to entire "pokemon" SQL database: https://www.discoduroderoer.es/ejercicios-propuestos-y-resueltos-consultas-sql-bd-pokemon/

Thanks for the help. I am new on posting in this community but it is not the first time I used and enjoyed it. 
Thanks for all

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation? And note that since 1992, this community (MySQL) would consider that 'correct' answer to be incorrect. Your answer is the 'correct' one (for MySQL) - although, as I said at the outset, I doubt that the LOWER() function is required.

Comment: fisrt of all, thanks for your repply. well i know that the " correct " way has to be using JOIN and thats why i create this post. because my answer is not working. has to have some error on it but i cant find it. And about the lower function i didnt try if it works without it but i put it to practice and dont forget that tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the where and join should word fine. the problem is that you are joining the table "tipo_evolucion" ON the wrong field

fild Tipo_Evolucion in table FORMA-EVOLUCION is numeric (this is the foreing key). Fild Tipo_Evolucion in table TIPO_EVOLUCION is varchar2 (this is not the primary key)

the primary key in TIPO_EVOLUCION IS id_tipo_evolucion

So your inner join should be

```
JOIN tipo_evolucion t ON t.id_tipo_evolucion  = fo.tipo_evolucion
```

the query therefore is:

```
SELECT p.nombre
FROM pokemon p
     JOIN pokemon_forma_evolucion pfe ON p.numero_pokedex = pfe.numero_pokedex
     JOIN forma_evolucion fo ON pfe.id_forma_evolucion = fo.id_forma_evolucion
     JOIN tipo_evolucion t ON t.id_tipo_evolucion  = fo.tipo_evolucion
WHERE LOWER(t.tipo_evolucion) = 'intercambio';
```